# Keycloak Custom Form Provider: Form has wrong action url

Tags: keycloak, redhat-sso

I have a custom form added to RestCredentialFlow, 
I can configure the new flow execution and I see the new Form. Looks all good.

The only problem is that  the form action url points to *registration* and not *reset-credentials*,

```
   <form id="kc-reset-password-form" class="sb-form-box" action="http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/soka/login-actions/registration?session_code=**&amp;execution=478d7632-2821-42f1-9c34-aa013fea33eb&amp;client_id=account&amp;" method="post">
      ...

      </form>
```

I can change it in the browser an everything works fine.

Can anybody help, why it points to registration and how to change it.
I don't see any interaction with the registration flow.

Thanks

Here the form is rendered, this already return the form with the wrong actionUrl.

```
public class ResetCredentialPage implements FormAuthenticator, FormAuthenticatorFactory {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ResetCredentialPage.class);

    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "reset-credential-page-form";

    @Override
    public Response render(FormContext context, LoginFormsProvider form) {
         return form.createPasswordReset();
    }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've found the answer yet, I'm in the exact same position.  Based on my reading of the documentation I strongly suspect the FormAction/FormAuthenticator classes are designed for the registration page only.  So the action uri is not meant to be anything other than the registration uri - basically I suspect it's hard coded somewhere more or less.

If I'm wrong let me know.